# it shows only one parents item in child which is clicked first on all other parent item for expandableListview

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

My below code shows only one parents item in child which is clicked first on all other parent item for `expandableListview`

```
    public class AffiliationAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
        Context context;
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
        // child data in format of header title, child title
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> _listDataChild;
        DbFields dbFields = new DbFields();


        public AffiliationAdapter(Context activity, List<String> listDataHeader, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listDataChild) {

            this.context = activity;
            this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
            this._listDataChild = listDataChild;
        }


        @Override
        public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver dataSetObserver) {

        }

        @Override
        public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver dataSetObserver) {

        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return this._listDataHeader.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
            return this._listDataChild.get(groupPosition).get(childPosititon);
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return false;
        }



        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


            if (view == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.faq_group_expand, null);
            }

            TextView getFaqAnswer = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.answer);

            getFaqAnswer.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            getFaqAnswer.setText((_listDataHeader.get(i)));

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
        {
            int result = 0;
            if (groupPosition == getGroupCount()-1)//logical fail ?
            {
                result = 1;
            }
            return result;

        }



        @Override
        public View getChildView(final int i, int i2, boolean b, View v, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

            if (v==null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_affiliation, null);
                int itemType = getChildType(i, i2);


                LinearLayout layout_about = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.layout_about);
                LinearLayout layout_vc = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.layout_vc);
                LinearLayout layout_registrar = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.layout_registrar);
                LinearLayout layout_examination_controller = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.layout_examination_controller);
                LinearLayout layout_link = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.layout_link);

                TextView about_detail = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.about_detail);
                TextView vc_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.vc_name);
                TextView vc_Contact = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.vc_Contact);
                TextView vc_email = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.vc_email);

                TextView registrar_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.registrar_name);
                TextView registarar_Contact = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.registarar_Contact);
                TextView registrar_email = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.registrar_email);


                TextView controller_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.controller_name);
                TextView controller_Contact = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.controller_Contact);
                TextView controller_email = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.controller_email);
                TextView link = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.link);

                about_detail.setText(_listDataChild.get(i2).get(dbFields.AFFILIATION_DESCRIPTION));
                vc_name.setText(_listDataChild.get(i2).get(dbFields.VC_NAME));
                vc_Contact.setText(_listDataChild.get(i2).get(dbFields.VC_PHONE));
                vc_email.setText(_listDataChild.get(i2).get(dbFields.VC_EMAIL));

                registrar_name.setText(_listDataChild.get(i2).get(dbFields.REGISTRAR_NAME));
                registarar_Contact.setText(_listDataChild.get(i2).get(dbFields.REGISTRAR_PHONE));
                registrar_email.setText(_listDataChild.get(i2).get(dbFields.REGISTRAR_EMAIL));

                controller_name.setText(_listDataChild.get(i2).get(dbFields.EXAM_CONTROLLER_NAME));
                controller_Contact.setText(_listDataChild.get(i2).get(dbFields.EXAM_CONTROLLER_PHONE));
                controller_email.setText(_listDataChild.get(i2).get(dbFields.EXAM_CONTROLLER_EMAIL));

                link.setText("Notice Link :" +_listDataChild.get(i2).get(dbFields.AFFILIATION_NOTICE_LINK)+
                        "\n Result Link : "+_listDataChild.get(i2).get(dbFields.AFFILIATION_RESULT_LINK)+
                        " \n Schedule Link :"+_listDataChild.get(i2).get(dbFields.AFFILIATION_SCHEDULE_LINK));




                int grup_pos = (int) getGroupId(i);
                switch (grup_pos) {
                    case 0:
                        layout_link.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        layout_examination_controller.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        layout_registrar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        layout_vc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        layout_about.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //   v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_contact, null);
                        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "position is" + grup_pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        layout_link.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        layout_examination_controller.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        layout_registrar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        layout_vc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        layout_about.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //   v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_faq_answer, null);
                        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "position is" + grup_pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        layout_link.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        layout_examination_controller.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        layout_registrar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        layout_vc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        layout_about.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //     v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_contact, null);
                        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "position is" + grup_pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
    //                case 3:
    //                    layout_link.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //                    layout_examination_controller.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //                    layout_registrar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //                    layout_vc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //                    layout_about.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //               //     v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events_items, null);
    //                    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "position is" + grup_pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //                    break;
                    case 3:
                        layout_link.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        layout_examination_controller.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        layout_registrar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        layout_vc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        layout_about.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //     v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_program, null);
                        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "position is" + grup_pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        layout_link.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        layout_examination_controller.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        layout_registrar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        layout_vc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        layout_about.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_program, null);
                        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "position is" + grup_pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
            //     v.invalidate();
            return v;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i2) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpanded(int i) {
            super.onGroupExpanded(i);


        }

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapsed(int i) {
            super.onGroupCollapsed(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getCombinedChildId(long l, long l2) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getCombinedGroupId(long l) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

**this is my main activity**
My below code shows only one parents item in child which is clicked first on all other parent item for `expandableListview` this is main activity

```
public class AffiliationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ExpandableListView expandableListView;
int previousItem = -1;


//variables to holds course entities
// Getting data from


LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
DbHelper dbHelper;
DbFields dbFields;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> affiliationChildList;
List<String> faqListHeader;
ScrollView scrollView;
LinearLayout mainLayout,header;
CC_Application application;
Intent intent;
String collegeId;
TextView estdDate,setting,location,type,totAffiliation,totStudent,universityName,fax,phone,email,staff_num;


private ArrayList<String> parentItems = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_affiliation);

    //initialise all fields

    expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandListViewFaq);
    layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
    dbFields = new DbFields();
    dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);
    mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    header = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.header);
    faqListHeader = new ArrayList<>();
    application= CC_Application.getInstance();

    estdDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.estd_date);
    setting = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.setting);
    location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
    type = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.type);
    totAffiliation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total_affiliation);
    totStudent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totStudent);
    universityName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleC);
    fax = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fax);
    phone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phone);
    email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    staff_num = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.staff_num);

    intent = getIntent();
    if(intent!=null) {
        collegeId = intent.getStringExtra("getCollegeId").toString();
    }


    //set parent name for the child

    parentItems.add("About Us");
    parentItems.add("VC");
    parentItems.add("Registrar");
    parentItems.add("Examination Controller");
    parentItems.add("Links");

    //set actionbar customized logo

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.college_connect_logo));

    affiliationChildList = application.getAllAffiliationList(collegeId);

    //hold data in expandable listview through adapter
    AffiliationAdapter adapter =  new AffiliationAdapter(this, parentItems, affiliationChildList);

    expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    estdDate.setText(affiliationChildList.get(0).get(dbFields.AFFILIATION_FOUNDATION_YEAR));
    setting.setText(affiliationChildList.get(0).get(dbFields.AFFILIATION_SETTING));
    universityName.setText(affiliationChildList.get(0).get(dbFields.AFFILIATION_NAME));
    type.setText(affiliationChildList.get(0).get(dbFields.AFFILIATION_TYPE));
    totAffiliation.setText(affiliationChildList.get(0).get(dbFields.AFFILIATION_AFFILIATED_COLLEGE_NUMBER));
    totStudent.setText(affiliationChildList.get(0).get(dbFields.AFFILIATION_ENROLLED_STUDENTS));
    location.setText(affiliationChildList.get(0).get(dbFields.AFFILIATION_ADDRESS));
    fax.setText(affiliationChildList.get(0).get(dbFields.AFFILIATION_FAX));
    phone.setText(affiliationChildList.get(0).get(dbFields.AFFILIATION_PHONE));
    email.setText(affiliationChildList.get(0).get(dbFields.AFFILIATION_EMAIL));
    staff_num.setText(affiliationChildList.get(0).get(dbFields.AFFILIATION_ACADEMIC_STAFF_NUMBER));

    expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            if (groupPosition != previousItem){
                expandableListView.collapseGroup(previousItem);
                previousItem = groupPosition;
                mainLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
            else{
                expandableListView.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
                previousItem = -1;
                mainLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }
    });

    // Listview Group collasped listener
    expandableListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
            mainLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Group Collapsed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_affiliation, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

mainactivity included.

Comment: i have 5 parent items , when i clicked on any one parent it shows its details(child items). after i clicked on other parent it shows the same child items of first parent i have clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess in your `getChildView()` method you have written code in one if condition i.e `if(v==null)`, just write initialisation code in that if and assigning data to your view write that code outside that if condition.

as when you click on next header(parent) no new view will inflated, because this time view will be not null.

Comment: it shows child of parent1 but when i clicked on other parent application crashed

Comment: what is error you are getting? can you post your logcat for error

Comment: 11-09 12:42:20.272 18057-18057/com.tagconsulting E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
11-09 12:42:20.272 18057-18057/com.tagconsulting E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
11-09 12:42:20.272 18057-18057/com.tagconsulting E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
11-09 12:42:20.272 18057-18057/com.tagconsulting E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.tagconsulting.collegeconnect.adapter.AffiliationAdapter.getChildView(AffiliationAdapter.java:171)

Comment: that means your child data arraylist has only one child for that parent so to access that your index should be "0" nut you are accessing with index "1". that why your are getting this error.

Comment: now please try modifying your code with Ranjit Pati's answer.

Comment: i have to change getChildrenCount from return1 to  return 0  ?

Comment: its should not be hard coded, its must be dynamic according to size of children data for respective parent. and for that please refer answer given by "Ranjit Pati"

Comment: after ranjits change , 11-09 13:06:54.675 31109-31109/com.tagconsulting E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-09 13:06:54.675 31109-31109/com.tagconsulting E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.tagconsulting.collegeconnect.adapter.AffiliationAdapter.getChildView(AffiliationAdapter.java:167)

Comment: actually i have set my child as 1, it never changes.

Comment: means your child count for each parent is only 1 right? then make your that value of getChildrenCount from return1 to return 0

Comment: when changed to return 0, the child is not shown. But application is not crashed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to pass the appropreate child size not 1. A small change:

From :

```
@Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return 1;
    }
```

To

```
@Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return _listDataChild .size();
    }
```

**EDIT**

And when you are getting the child as well.

From:

```
 @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(groupPosition).get(childPosititon);
    }
```

To:

Just try(Not sure):

```
 @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(childPosititon);
    }
```